# Where can I ask questions/file bug reports regarding all Beta sites?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0, beta-phase

I just asked [two](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223/line-containing-bounty-is-too-small) [questions](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/when-submission-fails-leave-the-state-of-the-notify-checkbox) on meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com, but they are not only related to their parent site, but to all Beta sites.

What is the best place to ask these kind of questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **Meta Central**,

the repository of all that's good and bad about the Stack Exchange universe in its entirety.

If you have a question that will apply to all sites you're welcome to place it here.